# script 'index.phtml' not found

Tags: zend-framework

I have used following code in IndexController:

```
$view = new Zend_View(array('scriptPath' =>'C:\Users\398853\Documents\NetBeansProjects\PhpProject3\application\views\scripts')); 
 echo $view->render('index.phtml');
```

But error is displayed as `script 'index.phtml' not found in path (C:\Users\398853\Documents\NetBeansProjects\PhpProject3\application\views\scripts/)`

I think the error occured because in script path '/' added instead of '\' at end.If yes then what is the solution for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the relative path to the script with the script path as base path so:

```
$view = new Zend_View(array('scriptPath' =>'C:\Users\398853\Documents\NetBeansProjects\PhpProject3\application\views\scripts'));
echo $view->render('index/index.phtml');
```

Should work. This is expecting you mean index action of index controller.

The directory separators are not important to PHP. If you want to be 100% on the save side use the constant DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR like this:

```
$path = array(APPLICATION_PATH, 'views', 'scripts');
$view = new Zend_View(array('scriptPath' => implode(DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $path));
```

Answer (score 0):

You should always use `/` instead of `\` when you specify paths as it works both in windows and linux

```
$view = new Zend_View(array('scriptPath' =>'C:/Users/398853/Documents/NetBeansProjects/PhpProject3/application/views/scripts'));
```

And you should definitely use a relative path, not an absolute one as you are doing i think

Answer (score 0):

In PHP, always use forward slashes for paths. PHP will translate to the OS-specific directory separator for you:

```
$view = new Zend_View(array('scriptPath' =>'C:/Users/398853/Documents/NetBeansProjects/PhpProject3/application/views/scripts'));
```

When you use backslashes, PHP has **NO** way to know that you're actually specifying a path, so it treats them as escapes, so in effect your path came out to be:

```
C:Users398853DocumentsNetBeansProjectsetc....
```

which is highly unlikely to exist on your machine.

Comment: Based on the error message OP supplied it would seem as though the code in `Zend_View` is escaping the path separator if it is \.

Answer (score 0):

The direction of the slash actually shouldn't matter. You're getting this error because there is no file named index.phtml in ..\views\scripts

Answer (score 0):

Using IDEs, check the correct upload of your files. Just struggled twenty minutes to find that.